# Active directory errors when checking login credentials in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, active-directory

I have an intranet where I have our users login with their AD credentials.

I thought I had everything trapped pretty well but this morning users were reporting that they couldn't login.

They were getting the following error, -2147023688

```
Active Directory error '800704b8' 

An extended error has occurred.  

/login/index.asp, line 26
```

Seems like it's related to passwords expiring.

I thought I had that covered with error -2147022989 which explicitly states that the password has expired at which point I redirect the user to a password change screen where they can update it via ASP.

Is there anyway to get more info on the extended error or is there list of numerical errors and their corresponding descriptions?

Or even better, should I just ignore this error completely, allow them to login and they'll just change their password the next time they login to their PCs?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think IIS will allow a user to change their AD password. It's too many layers removed, if that makes sense. If you want to use AD to handle website security, you *must* set the passwords to never expire. (Expiring passwords is a bunch of hogwash, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Martha is incorrect. Your code can in fact change user passwords if it has the necessary permissions to do so. Your site will need to be running as a user account within AD. You did not mention which version of IIS you are using so it's impossible to give you specific instructions on how to configure your site.

That said, granting your site permissions to modify user passwords is a security risk you should weigh against the necessity of your site to make these sorts of changes. If your site were to be compromised, the attacker would be able to execute commands in the same security context as your site. So the attacker could potentially reset passwords for users and login as them and use this to escalate their attack.

You will have decide if the convenience offered by your code and the potential security risks are worth the reward.

Comment: If your site is running as a user account within AD, then why would you need to log in under AD? In other words, there's a chicken-and-egg problem here.

Comment: He needs to log in to AD to change user passwords via his web application. That's the whole point. Not to be rude, but there is something you're clearly not understanding. Here is a doc discussing the minimum permissions necessary to reset user passwords: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296999. To be clear, he's not configuring IIS to login as the user, he's configuring IIS to login as a service account that has permissions to reset other users passwords. That service account needs to be a domain member in order to have the necessary permissions to reset user passwords.

Comment: Except that the OP clearly wants the *users* to have the ability to change their passwords. If he wanted an admin to change it for them, there'd be no need to do it through IIS.

Comment: The users can change their passwords by proxy of this service account with the appropriate coding. You are incorrect and I'll leave it at that.